# Are there any folding adult tricycles on the market in the UK?

Tags: tricycle, transport-by-car

It is easy to find folding bike, but where do you get a folding tricycles?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any recumbent tricycles that can be transported with a normal car?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/515/are-there-any-recumbent-tricycles-that-can-be-transported-with-a-normal-car)

Comment: I think its more a duplicate of http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/518/where-uk-can-we-rent-an-adult-tricycle-or-recumbent-tricycle in that its asking region specific info. For this reason I voted to close (this and that one). The question related to transporting in tricycle in car is OK in my view because its not region specific.

Comment: This question is clearly generating a list. Voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Azub Eco [recumbent tadpole] Trike](http://www.azub.eu/CZ/azub-eco-trike/). However, if you watch the [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmnkAviUFBU) of the folding, it's no Brompton.

Comment: Yeah, I would describe that as less of a folding bike and more along the lines of "easily disassembled".  It would fit in your trunk though, which would make it nice for travelling.  But not something I would use for commuting.

Comment: @Kibbee Something gets folded at 1:53 in the video!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Di Blasi folding tricycles.  I don't have any experience with them but their fold look as cool as the Brompton fold.

http://www.diblasi.co.uk/Folding_Tricycles.asp?Prd=Tricycles&Pag=Gruppo&Lng=en

Answer (score 0):

The Pashley [Tri-1](http://www.pashley.co.uk/products/tri-1.html) doesn't fold very small, but is transportable by car.

Answer (score 0):

ICE Trikes are made and presumably sold in the UK.

http://www.icetrikes.co/