# Where (UK) can we rent an adult tricycle or recumbent tricycle

Tags: recumbent, tricycle, uk

There are a lot of cycle tracks (mostly old railway lines) in the UK that have bike rental, however very few of them have adult tricycle or recumbent tricycle.

Does anyone have the list of where you can rent an adult tricycle in the UK?

Comment: I voted to close because this is too region specific. Here's a discussion on meta.bicycles that covers  asking region specific questions. 
http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2/suggesting-bike-routes-allowed

Comment: @Kevin, most questions are regional to some extent, as the law on cycling is regional and most bikes are only sold in some regions.   I think saying that the UK is too region specific is taking it a bit too fare, as a lot of questions/answers could then be closed on the grounds that they cover products that are only on the market in the USA.

Comment: Its worth clarifying what the community thinks on this, so I've opened a question on meta to discuss: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/60/another-regional-specific-question-are-these-ok-or-not

Answer (score 5):

Where abouts in the UK are you?  You might want to check out the following places:

- London Recumbants - http://www.londonrecumbents.co.uk/bikes_we_hire.html
- DTek - don't have a web site but can be emailed on dtekhpvs@btopenworld.com
- FutureCycles - futurecycles.co.uk

Hope you get sorted.

Comment: thanks, given we can plan where we go on holiday we are not tied to one location in the uk.

Answer (score 3):

Battersea Park in London has these for rental for both adults/kids. It's only for riding around the park, but this is probably a safer place to experiment on than London's roads...

Answer (score 2):

Near Bristol, [Strawberry Line Cycles](https://strawberry-line-cycles.booqable.shop/) have a range of interesting bikes and trikes for atypical users, including adult trikes, adapted trikes for riders with disabilities, and tandem trikes.  I found them very helpful (when I wanted to hire a tandem) to try out with my daughter. They're located right on a long traffic-free gravel bike path (disused railway) so have nice riding on the doorstep.