# High End Bicycle Rentals in New York City

Tags: mountain-bike

Does anyone know of any shops that rent high end bikes like Santa Cruz, Titus, etc. by the week or month? I've checked SpeedGoat, Competitive Cyclist and the rest of the usual suspects.

Ideally I'd like a carbon 29'r with 5" of rear travel.

Comment: It sounds like your question is "regional" -- where, generally speaking, do you live?

Comment: for the record, "regional" is a deprecated tag (I tried to use it). Instead, it is advised to use the country/region/continent, either in the question or via tagging.

Comment: We allow regional questions about trails and routes, and there's [precedent](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/518/8) for rental questions. (See [this thread in meta](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/60/8).) However, the upvoted answer goes on to suggest that regional questions be made into Community Wiki, something we no longer do. I think this issue should be raised again. Until then, I think we cal allow this.

Comment: Have added the user's location to the title of the question.

Comment: The OP didn't specify a region, or limit the question to his own area. This is likely not possible to find outside of a few cycling vacation spots.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, you will only find high end off road bike rentals in high traffic cycling vacation spots, like Whistler-Blackcomb resort, or Moab, Utah.

These places and similar destinations are the only places where a large number of riders who want or need high end off road bikes, and are willing to pay enough money to make it practical to rent those bikes, will come through regularly without their own bikes.

Otherwise, for local rentals, people either want more basic machines due to cost. Or the cost of the machine doesn't balance with the number of people willing to pay enough to justify purchasing it to begin with.